# How to get topology with squared faces using Bezier curves when converted to mesh

Tags: bezier-curves, topology

I'm drawing out shapes using the Bezier curve, and when its converted to mesh, the topology is divided up, but the spacing isn't good to make perfect circles on the mesh. The topology to get better circle shapes must be a square. But as seen in the example of the handlebars and abstract shape, when curve is converted to mesh, its not square, but rather a rectangle shape.

Is there a method to control how the mesh gets its topology when converted?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could try to go with geometry nodes like this:

[image]

The resample curve can be set to Length, and if you set the length with a mathematical equation to your radius, you could try to get squares. But of course because of the bending of the curve you won't have always squares, but maybe a bit improvement?

[image]

Comment: Hi Chris, its not about the bevel, but the topology of the mesh. As you can see in this image, I did it extruding the mesh face ( control + left mouse click ), into a handle bar object. Then I divided the mesh equally as much possible making square topology. The I was able to get a nice circle using the LoopTools. And then extruding the circle making the handlebar round. But when I use the bezier curve, when I turn the curve into a mesh, its rectangle shape mesh. This is what Id like to know if I can control in the Object Data Properties, the flow of the mesh.

https://ibb.co/hYzsFMB

Comment: Another example: https://ibb.co/PtNSLgw

Comment: ah ok, got it, thx for explanation, i updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

*A bit of info what is happening here ...*

You control grid by Resolution by two values (mark by pink circle)

[image]

...but even you set square at one control point it generates rectangle at another point. It is that because of bezier curve type and its handle position. Handles control interpolation in between control points.

[image]

The only way with this kind of curve to generate even grid handles has to be at a middle of distance to another control point.

[image]

That is not convenient if you need to shape your curve of course. So you would have to use another approach. Like Geometry Nodes ([answered by Chris](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/279558/2214)) where curve can be resampled with a specific distance.

Or use one curve with corrected handles (or mesh with right topology already) and deform it by another curve via modifier.